# Can I configure codeigniter to avoid all htmlentities?

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-entities

I have a huge codeigniter app, with lots of forms and fields. I need to avoid users to enter HTML code in any input. I know I can escape it which funcionts like `strip_tags` or escape it using `htmlentites`.

But I wonder if there is any way to do it globally, that remove or escapes the html code inserted in any of the inputs of the whole aplication.

Comment: i don't even understand what you mean, afaik CI uses `htmlspecialchars` only in a function called `html_escape` which is used by the form helper

Comment: I mean, in the same way like this avoid the sql injection, I want configure it to save htmlentities, and/or to get the results converting htmltntities to avoid load html when I show it in the page.

Comment: But I want to di it in all the application, without change each file to evaluate htmlentities

Comment: you've to provide an example with a model, controller and view in order to understand what you want

Comment: The problem is when I already have the application, all the application and is so big. So how can you do to dont save html data or at least whos html like  texts in all the aplication?, i mean something from the database

Answer (score 1):

I've modifiyed the function that retrieve results, filtering the html open and close tag. that is something like I want. to deny show html or javascript saved in the database.

```
public function array_htmlentities(&$row){
        //return $row;
        foreach($row as &$value){
            if( is_array($value) || is_array($value) ){
                $value = $this->array_htmlentities($value);
            }elseif(is_string($value)){
                $json = json_decode($value);
                if( is_array($json) || is_array($json) ){
                    $value = json_encode($this->array_htmlentities($json));
                }else
                    $value = str_replace(array('<','>'), array('&lt;','&gt;'), $value);
                //$value = $value;
            }else
                $value = $value;
        }

        return $row;
    }
```